# Is it better to destructure a value to access attributes or use their names?

Tags: rust

In the [Rust by Example chapter about methods](http://rustbyexample.com/fn/methods.html), I saw the following code to calculate the area of a `Rectangle`:

```
struct Rectangle {
    p1: Point,
    p2: Point,
}

impl Rectangle {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 {
        let Point { x: x1, y: y1 } = self.p1;
        let Point { x: x2, y: y2 } = self.p2;
        ((x1 - x2) * (y1 - y2)).abs()
    }
}
```

Personally, I would have done something like:

```
fn area(&self) -> f64 {
    ((self.p1.x - self.p2.x) * (self.p1.y - self.p2.y)).abs()
}
```

Is the tutorial code better than mine and if so, why?

Comment: Yours looks correct, but that one statement is a bit too wordy for my liking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that you are completely missing the point.

The example is *just* about demonstrating a particular syntax; it does not attempt to claim that this syntax is the best way to achieve *this particular task*.

Examples of syntax are always limited, especially when self-contained, to snippet where their benefits are not immediately evident. This does not mean the syntax is necessarily superfluous.

---

The syntax under scrutiny can be useful in two situations:

- it can reduce noise, by allowing naming quickly the few pertinent elements for a computation
- it also allows *destructuring*, consuming the left-hand side (if not `Copy`) and naming its constituents in one fell swoop; indeed, this is nothing more than one instance (among others) of pattern matching

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was asking for.
I know that they will do the same thing I was only wondering about the benefit of their syntax.